# Error in assignment maximizing minimal quality in R language from the book example

Tags: r, linear-programming

I was trying run the example given in the textbook named "Modeling and Solving Linear Programming with R" the link to the textbook can be found [here](http://www.omniascience.com/scholar/index.php/scholar/article/download/20/15)

I tried copying the exact code from the chapter 3.8 on page 75 but it seems that it prints out different result

```
Assignment01 <- function(c){
n <- dim(c)[1]
coef <- as.vector(t(c))
rhs <- rep(1,2*n)

Amatrix <- matrix(0, 2*n, n*n)

for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        Amatrix[i, n*(i-1)+j] <- 1
    }
}

for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        Amatrix[n+i, n*(j-1)+i] <- 1
    }
}

signs <- rep("==", 2*n)
var_type <- rep("B", 2*n)
library(Rglpk)

solution <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj=coef, mat=Amatrix, dir=signs, types=var_type, rhs=rhs, max=TRUE)
return(solution)

}

Assignment02 <- function(c){
n <- dim(c)[1]
coef <- c(rep(0, n*n),1)
rhs <- c(rep(1, 2*n), rep(0,n))
Amatrix <- matrix(0, 3*n, n*n + 1)

for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        Amatrix[i, n*(i-1)+j] <- 1
    }
}

for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        Amatrix[n+i, n*(j-1)+i] <- 1
    }
}

for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        Amatrix[2*n+1, n*(j-1)+i] <- c[j,i]
    }
}

for(i in 1:n){
    Amatrix[2*n+1, n*n + 1] <- -1

}

signs <- c(rep("==", 2*n),rep(">=",n))

var_type <- c(rep("B", n*n), "C")

library(Rglpk)

solutionPL <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj=coef, mat=Amatrix, dir=signs, types=var_type, rhs=rhs, max=TRUE)
return (solutionPL) 
}


set.seed(1)
c <- matrix(sample(10:100, 25),100,100)
solAss01 <- Assignment01(c)
m.01 <- matrix(solAss01$solution[1:25],5,5, byrow=TRUE)
solAss02 <- Assignment02(c)
m.02 <- matrix(solAss02$solution[1:25],5,5,byrow=TRUE)
print(m.01)
print(m.02)
```

and got this output

[image]

that should be 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code does not compile:

```
for(j in 1:){
```

I believe you are confusing `x(i,j)` with `c(i,j)`. The `x` values are zeros and ones with only one `1` in each row and column.

Also notice your `c(i,j)` have the same value for each `j`:

```
> c[1:5,1:5]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   34   34   34   34   34
[2,]   43   43   43   43   43
[3,]   60   60   60   60   60
[4,]   89   89   89   89   89
[5,]   27   27   27   27   27
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the typographical error, I accidentally did that on submitting here on stackoverflow, it should be for(j in 1:n), its the same in my code and still shows the same output as shown above in my post will try to edit it so others wont be having compile error, thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I'm really confused with x(i,j) part in the code I still can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: Try a smaller `5 x 5` example (instead of `100 x 100`) with the `c(i,j)` as shown in tables 3.19 and 3.20. The bold numbers should indicate where `x(i,j)=1'.

Comment: Use   `c <- matrix(sample(10:100, 25),5,5)` in your script to replicate the results.

Comment: I found another way around. thank you so much to your help. I really helped me around to solve the issue i'm facing